# Given a call stack containing a lambda function, how can one determine its source?

Tags: c++, debugging, lambda

Suppose you have some code that pushes onto a queue like this:

```
template <typename T>
void submitJobToPool(T callable)
{
    someJobQueue.push(callable)
}
```

...and later on:

```
template <typename T>
void runJobFromPool(T callable)
{
    auto job = someJobQueue.pop();
    job();
}
```

Now imagine that the code crashes due to some error inside of the `job()` call. If the submitted job was a normal function, the call stack might look something like this:

```
void myFunction()     0x345678901
void runJobFromPool() 0x234567890
int main(int, char**) 0x123456789
```

It's easy to see what function crashed here. If it's a functor, it'll be similar but with an `operator()` in there somewhere (ignoring inlining). However, for a lambda...

```
void lambda_a7009ccf8810b62b59083b4c1779e569() 0x345678901
void runJobFromPool()                          0x234567890
int main(int, char**)                          0x123456789
```

This is not so easy to debug. If there's a debugger attached when it happens, or a core dump available, then that information can be used to derive which lambda crashed, but that information is not always available. As far as I know, disassembly is one of the few ways to determine what crashed from this.

The ideas I've had to make this better are:

1. Using a tool like `addr2line` if the platform supports it. This sometimes works, sometimes not.
2. Wrapping up all lambdas in functors (not ideal, to say the least).
3. Not using lambdas (again, not ideal).
4. Using a compiler extension to give the lambda a more meaningful name / add debugging info.

The 4th option sounded promising, so I did some investigation, but couldn't find anything. In case it matters, the compilers I have available are clang++ 5.0 and MSVC 19 (Visual Studio 2015).

My question is, what other tools / techniques are available that can help map a callstack with a lambda function in it to the corresponding source line?

Comment: With `clang++` did you compile with `clang++ -g -O0` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sometimes yes, sometimes no, it depends on the configuration used. Often debugging info is added with compiler optimisations on. The original internal issue was raised with MSVC, but I've had similar problems on clang++ in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible. You should design your own technique how to store required information in lamdas. Your option 2 is suitable here. You may look how does it Google: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/base/task_scheduler/post_task.h

Below is very raw approach (https://ideone.com/OFCgAq)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <functional>

std::stack<std::function<void(void)>> someJobQueue;

template <typename T>
void submitJobToPool(std::string from_here, T callable) {
    someJobQueue.push(std::bind([callable](std::string from_here) { callable(); }, from_here));
}

void runJobFromPool() {
    auto job = someJobQueue.top();
    someJobQueue.pop();
    job();
}

int main() {
    submitJobToPool(__func__, [](){ std::cout << "It's me." << std::endl; });
    runJobFromPool();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately you will not see a perfect call stack. But you can see `from_here` in a debugger.

```
void lambda_1a7009ccf8810b62b59083b4c1779e56() 0x345678920
void lambda_a7009ccf8810b62b59083b4c1779e569() 0x345678910  <-- Here `from_here` will be available: "main"
void runJobFromPool()                          0x234567890
int main(int, char**)                          0x123456780
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if the parameter gets placed into the class stack, but even if it doesn't, some error handling code could keep track of what was running when it crashed at least. Using constant strings, the overhead shouldn't be too bad I think

Comment: Similar to a technique I used years ago in a multithreaded program.  Called the `char const*` literal a breadcrumb, which was invaluable for figuring out where cross-thread events came from.  Would work well here, too.  If you can guarantee using C++ string literals via superhuman discipline, you can avoid the `std::string` and just have the pointer to the `char const*`.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to create a struct (ideally via a script) that has multiple functions (one for each lambda) and call the lambda via this struct strictly. These functions could just take this lambda and execute it.

This struct method will show up in the crash logs and the stack trace.

```
struct LambdaCrashLogs {
    Lambda1(std::function<void(void)> job) {
        job();
    }
};
```

The main approach will be to write a pre-commit script that generates this struct automatically.

Comment: Once you've done this, I'm not sure what the point is of using lambdas anymore, since you've just written the boilerplate code that the lambda was meant to replace :)

Comment: The advantage is that you can move this off to code generation scripts and keep it hidden from the day to day life of the developer and the reviewer.